Flip screen horizontally
Is there a way to flip the screen horizontally in Raspberry Pi OS?
The reason I need to do this is because I see the screen through a teleprompter mirror. Therefore I need to flip the entire screen horizontally, making left to right as well as right to left.
I was not able to find a working solution yet. Apparently x11 only supports turning the screen (Normal, Inverted, 90 degrees, and 270 degrees), but it does not seem to support flipping horizontally or vertically, which is what I need. Then there is Wayland, that seems to support flipping, but I could not find a way to activate it. The Raspberry Pi I use is the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+.

Apparently x11 ... does not seem to support flipping it (X11) seems to support flipping using xrandr command - not sure if that applies to raspberry pi though

making left to right as well as right to left ... how would you flip something left to right without also flipping it right to left?

@jsotola Aiming at being the most precise possible, it may just as well have overshoot the target! However, the logic is still valid! :)

@JaromandaX It seems xrandr is the way to go. At least until there is a more appropriate solution.

Can't you just add another mirror?
